# Как не вызывать событие OnOrderUpdate при удалении заказа?

Tags: php, битрикс, cms

Есть задача, повешать функцию на событие `OnOrderUpdate` и `OnBeforeOrderDelete`. Но при `OnBeforeOrderDelete` срабатывает и вызов обновления заказа, и вызывается та функция, которая мне не нужна. Как убрать вызов `OnOrderUpdate` при удалении заказа, или каким условием проверять внутри функции, не вызвана ли она при удалении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я все правильно понимаю то битрикс сначала пытается отменить все оплаты и сохраняет заказ, а уже после удаляет его.

вырвано из  `Bitrix\Sale\Compatible\OrderCompatibility::delete()`:

```
  /** @var Sale\PaymentCollection $paymentCollection */
    if ($paymentCollection = $order->getPaymentCollection())
    {
        /** @var Sale\Payment $payment */
        foreach ($paymentCollection as $payment)
        {
            if ($payment->isPaid())
            {
                $payment->setPaid('N');
            }
        }
        /** @var Sale\Result $r */
        $r = $order->save();   //<----- UPDATE
        if (!$r->isSuccess())
        {
            $result->addErrors($r->getErrors());
            return $result;
        }
    }

    /** @var Sale\Result $r */
    $r = Sale\Order::delete($id);  // <---- DELETE
```

Вывод: передавайте другим способом в обработчик `OnOrderUpdate`что собираетесь этот заказ удалить.

Comment: Как не пробавали, ничего путного не вышло... Благодарю за ответ. Подошли немного другим способом к решению задачи (через агентов).